# Create API for website

Tags: java, php, api, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I need to create public api for my website, like http://instagram.com/developer/ API or dropbox API.

I want to use oAuth2.0.  I need very basic functionality like getting user information, upload ,download, get, delete data etc.

I need to have SDKs in different languages like PHP, Java etc.

My website is in PHP 5 and the data stored is on dropbox and Amazon S3.

I also have an option to create my API server in Java, is that good option. I am totally new to API creation and need suggestions to start API.

Flow should be like this user create app on my website and get api,key and secret and then use get access tokens for users and then making calls.

Is there any opensource library to create such service and defining endpoints and APi explorer etc.

Thank You.

Comment: Search here or on a search engine for "Create REST service PHP". It doesn't matter too much what language your service is written in, so use the one you know best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of usefull sites you might want to look in:

- OAuth demo application: http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/
- Demo application on github:
  https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-demo-php/
- OAuth tutorial: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/

This will get you started with OAuth.

But your not there yet, OAuth is just a tool to get you there.
A good API requires a lot of thinking, because developers will probably implement your API it needs to be good from the start. i suggest you google a bit on good API practices.

Try youtube, search for API. You'll find a lot of interesting videos about this topic, for example:

Wikipedia on rest services: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Google on APIS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw

The API Guys: http://www.youtube.com/user/apigee